# Error handling message types

Tags: vb.net

I am using try..catch for error handling.  I am getting the message displayed as

```
messagebox.show (ex.tostring)
```

But it gives very long message.
Is it possible just to get only the actual error or I could give my own modified message, based on what ex contains?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Exception.Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx) property.

```
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the content of the `Message` property. Usually it's a short descriptive message without the full - technical - details of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

`Exception.Message` contains a simple description of the exception (e.g. "Object reference not set...").

`Exception.ToString()` contains a description of the exception along with a complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Message` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx) returns only the message(which explains the reason for the exception).

```
Dim message As String = "Message: " & ex.Message
MessageBox.Show(message)
```

However,  if you only want the [name of the Exception's Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name.aspx):

```
 Dim typeName = ex.GetType().Name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want less text in message then try to change

```
Exception.ToString to Exception.Message
```

as Massimiliano Peluso said, and if you want to customize then I hope this will give you some idea.

```
Try

'Your Codes...

Catch oledbEx As OleDbException

MessageBox.Show("Your message")

Catch ex As Exception

MessageBox.Show("Your message")

Catch ioEX As IOException

MessageBox.Show("Your message")

Catch dataEX As DataException

MessageBox.Show("Your message")

End Try
```